# What is a realization of a measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

My question is pretty straightforward. I've seen in some articles statements such as "this measure can be realized on..." but I've never found a definition of a "realization of a measure". Does this mean something mathematically or it is just a way of saying "measure defined on..."?

Comment: Can you give some context?

Comment: It could be [Definition 1.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511545.pdf)